# Topological spin in $Z_2$ toric code

Tags: topological-order, topological-phase, anyons, topological-defects

On page 20 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438), Kitaev shows that the composite particle $\varepsilon = e \times m$ is a fermion. He also said that it is easy to show $e$ is a boson (i.e. carries a topological spin of 1). I am having trouble proving this result. What might be an appropriate process to consider to derive that $e$ is a boson? Would someone please help?

Comment: This model is described in detail in other paper, see [Toric code](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021).